# Пропорциональное заполнение ширины при Grid-разметке

Tags: html, css3, grid

Есть вот такая разметка используя `grid`:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}

.wrapper > div {
  background: gray;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
  <div>D</div>
  <div>E</div>
</div>
```

В определенный момент последние два блока переносятся на вторую строку. Что можно добавить, чтобы перенесенные блоки стали занимать пропорционально всю ширину по 50%, не прибегая к `flex`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Решение без `flex-*`**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вам нужна адаптивность, то лучше задавать колонки без фиксированных размеров. Размеры контента принято устанавливать в относительных единицах от его контейнера.

Вам нужно добавить в стиль `@media`, который будет изменять 2 последних элемента, когда вы сделаете экран меньше определенного значения.

В примере для наглядности использовал разделение экрана `grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);`, т.к. каждый элемент по умолчанию занимает 1 колонку.

Пример лучше посмотреть в [CodePen](https://codepen.io/dimanmup/pen/GRjyebv).

Когда сузите окно браузера, то экран разделится на 12 частей, т.к. 12 делится нацело на 3 и 2 (в 1й строке - 3 элемента, во 2й - 2 элемента). 2 последних элемента перейдут на 2ю строку и займут 6/12 ее ширины (12/2 элемента), а оставшиеся элементы на первой строке разделят 1ю строку поровну, т.е. займут по 4/12 ее ширины (12/3 элемента).

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .wrapper{
        grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr) !important;
    }
    .wrapper>div.col-50 {
        grid-column: span 6;
        grid-row: 2;
    }
    .wrapper>div{
        grid-column: span 4;
    }
}
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
}
.wrapper > div {
    background: gray;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 1px;
    flex: 1 1 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>С</div>
  <div class="col-50">D</div>
  <div class="col-50">E</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но, увы, для "динамического" контента это не подойдет. Я не знаю заранее сколько вложенных div-ов будет. Нужен перенос в зависимости и от количества элементов, и от их минимально-заданной ширины (которую, кстати, в один момент, можно тоже мочь править). `Flex`-ом это решается запросто. Но в документации по `grid`-верстке указано, что, она позволяет все то, что умеет `flex` и плюс еще второе направление (не столько в строки). Вот я и думаю, то ли я не понял написанного, то ли написано "слишком смело".

Comment: @Majestio Адаптивная верстка предполагет знать все варианты размещения. Если вы хотите нечто вроде универсального алгоритма, то это уже программирование разметки (php, Razor) или стиля (less, sass), но и в этом случае опять надо продумывать все варианты) Попробуйте зайти с этой стороны.

Comment: Да нет же! У нас есть "минимальная ширина" и требование "перенесенные блоки размещать пропорционально по ширине". А перенесенных блоков может быть - и один, и два ... и семь. `Flex` это позволяет без медиа запросов. А я ищу схожий функционал в `grid`.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант использовать флексы

```css
.wrapper {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.wrapper > div {
   flex: 1 1 200px;
}

.wrapper > div {
  flex: 1 1 200px; /* 100px */
  background: gray;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
  <div>D</div>
  <div>E</div>
</div>
```

Это скорее всего не то что нужно, но симуляция поведения флекса

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.wrapper div {
  min-width: 100px;
  background: gray;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1px;
}

.wrapper div:last-child {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
  <div>D</div>
  <div>E</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, с `flex`-ами я умею. Пытаюсь изучать `grid`-верстку.

Comment: есть решение найду дополню ответ

Comment: Я только "за"! :-)

Comment: @Majestio вероятно я все же ошибся, все таки насколько я знаю полностью флекс не заменим гридом, на всякий случай вставил решение с которым я перепутал его возможности